# Interchange name of db column in rails logically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a **table admin**. In which there are two columns **'username' and 'email'**. Since earlier app was in php, mistakenly the **email is being used for storing username and username for emails**.
Now we have migrated smaller part of application in rails, what I want is to **do some changes in rails model** so that **username points to email and email points to username**. I cannot rename column in db since it will break php side of app.

Is this possible in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create virtual attributes to set\get `username` and and `email` fields and define getter and setter methods. Some examples can be found here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes?view=asciicast

UPD:
Some code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def username
    self.email
  end

  def username=(name)
    self.email=name
    name
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Bob I need to do same thing for email. Won't code go in recursion?